# Can i rename the root path when creating module or component from angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I tried to rename the `app` to custom name and `app` module to custom module. and it worked well, 
But when i create any component or sub module with `ng g m sub-module` It takes the path as `app/moduleName/componentName`. how can i make `custom-name/moduleName/componentName` when creating a module from cli command.

Where do i customize this setting?

Answer (score 1):

Simply write the full path what you want, and the last segment will be the name of the module ex: `ng g m users/UserDetails` <--- will generates a `UserDetailsModule` in the `users` folder. You can do this with the component generate command, like this: `ng g c users/UserDetails --m users/UserDetails.module` <--- this will generates a component and will declares in the `UserDetailsModule`. See more options [here](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component-command).

**Update 1**

I found a solution: use `../` in the path, like this: `ng g c ../user` but when you use this, the CLI doesn't finds any module and will cries, soo you need add an extra option and the final command will be: `ng g c ../user --skipImport`.

**Updadte 2**

If you specifies the declaration modul, you can skip the `--skipImport` flag, like this: `ng g c ../dashboard --module app/app.module`

Comment: i tried this. It creates like `src/app/users/UserDetails`.
I am looking something like `src/users/UserDetails`.

Comment: I found a solution, use `../` in the path, like: `ng g c ../user --skipImport`

Comment: Thanks, this works. Looking for the config file to set that. thanks anyway.

Comment: If you specifies the module you can skip this `--skipImport`  option, like this: `ng g c ../dashboard --module app/app.module `